PowerApps patch function
I have a problem I'm stuck on. In my app I have connections to 2 tables. One is called Table_Collegas and the other Table_Deelnemers. I also have a text label called NextTraining01.
NextTraining01 will display either TrainingA, TrainingB or TrainingC depending on certain conditions.
The Table_Deelnemers has a column of emails and a column called aanwezig which has yes or no values.
Table_Collegas also has a column of emails, and the columns TrainingA, TrainingB and TrainingC. I would like to create a button that does the following:
If NextTraining01.Text = "TrainingA":

patch column TrainingA of Table_Collegas with the data from Aanwezig of Table_Deelnnemers for the rows with the same emails.

If NextTraining01.Text = "TrainingB":

patch column TrainingB of Table_Collegas with the data from Aanwezig of Table_Deelnnemers for the rows with the same emails.

If NextTraining01.Text = "TrainingC":

patch column TrainingC of Table_Collegas with the data from Aanwezig of Table_Deelnnemers for the rows with the same emails.

